# Node application crashing after receiving JSON, but not before sending it.

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a node.js application im trying to create, and part of it is reaching out to reddit's api and getting the JSON from a url, storing it in a URL and sending out what it gathered. It does all this but then after sending out the array of the objects it found, the application crashes with the error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
```

which doesnt make sense to me because it has already found those values and used them for the output. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
var express = require("express"),
restler = require("restler");

var app = express.createServer();

app.all('/:subreddit', function(req, res){
    restler.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/"+ req.params.subreddit + ".json").on('complete', function(reddit){
    var reddit_data = reddit.data.children;
    var titles = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    while (i<5){

        titles[i] = i+": " + reddit_data[i].data.title;
        i++
    }
    res.send(titles);
});
});

app.listen(14042);
console.log("redSMS listening on 14042");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you take *every* request and pass it to Reddit.

If the browser goes to, say `http://localhost/bmw`, express will pass it to reddit and show the results for `http://www.reddit.com/r/bmw.json`. So far so good.

Then the browser does what it always does, goes for `http://localhost/favicon.ico` which passes to Reddit as `http://www.reddit.com/r/favicon.ico.json`, gives a 404 and no result. When you try to access `children` of that result, you get the crash.

Comment: Ohhhh! I totally forgot about filtering out favicon.ico, thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah, just to confirm, that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The callback to the "complete" event handler gets passed 2 parameters, not one.  The first is the "result", and the second is the "response" object.